# Is $G = (\Bbb Q^*,a*b=\frac{a+b}{2})$ a group, monoid, semigroup or none of these?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups, monoid, magma

> Is $G = (\Bbb Q^*,a*b=\frac{a+b}{2})$ a group, monoid, semigroup or none of these?

I tried to solve it by assuming $ a,b,c \in G $ such that $a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c$. Then$$\frac{a+\frac{b+c}{2}}{2} = \frac{\frac{a+b}{2}+c}{2}$$

and by taking $$ 2\times\left(  \frac{a+\frac{b+c}{2}}{2} =  \frac{\frac{a+b}{2}+c}{2} \right) $$
we have $$ a+\frac{b+c}{2} =\frac{a+b}{2}+c.$$

In my steps I have $(G,*)$ is not associative. Are my steps right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by $a=n$ and $b=c=n+1$. This should be a counterexample to associativity.

so , that $∗$ is not associative

you can't continue because the Set is neither a group nor a monoid nor a semigroup.

Answer (score 7):

You haven't yet proved that the operation is not associative - you need to whip up an actual counterexample. Can you think of a particular choice of $a,b$, and $c$ for which we have $$a+{b+c\over 2}\not={a+b\over 2}+c?$$ (Certainly it *looks* unlikely that the two expressions would always be equal, but you haven't yet *proved* that they're not in general.)

Answer (score 5):

Just for the sport of it, a purely abstract proof (the right proof is of course to prove that $*$ is not associative).

Clearly, the operation $*$ is idempotent ($a*a = a$), commutative and cancellative ($a * b = a * c$ implies $b = c$). Thus, if $G$ was a semigroup, it would be a [cancellative semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup) and a [semilattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice) and hence would be trivial (since in such a semigroup, $ab = aab = bab$ implies $a=b$).

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=2$ and $b=c=1$. This should be a counterexample to associativity.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct! Though to show that $*$ is not associative, you should give an explicit counterexample. Your working out should let you construct one easily, but until you have many would say it is not a proof.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: thanks ,  if you have Suitable Proof please Write it to learn what i should do next time

Comment: The suitable proof is to provide a counter example! That is, to provide concrete values $a,b,c$ for which $(a*b)*c \neq a*(b*c)$.

Answer (score 2):

Subtract $\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ from both sides of your last equation, and you get an equation that's quite easy to violate.

Answer (score 0):

you can't continue because the Set is neither a group nor a monoid  nor a semigroup.

Comment: thank you all problem solved